# JQuery - hour spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I need to use the JQuery spinner for hours so the template will be:
00:00:00:00

Currently the spinner is set only for numbers.

How can I do it?

Comment: What kind of time notation uses four colons?

Comment: hours:minutes:seconds:frames
where there are 30 frames in a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to have a spinner for each number. I set up [a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/EF28s/).

HTML

```
<div class="demo">
 <p>
  <label for="amount">Set the time (hh:mm:ss:fr):</label>
  <input class="time hour" name="hour" value="0" />
  <input class="time min" name="min" value="0" />
  <input class="time sec" name="sec" value="0" />
  <input class="time frames" name="frames" value="0" />
 </p>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
 $(".time").spinner({
  min: 0,
  max: 59,
  step: 1,
  start: 0,
  precision: 0,
  width: '2em'
 });    
 $(".hour").spinner('option','max', 23);
 $(".frames").spinner('option', 'max', 100);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it in one input box, and when the status is 00:00:59:00 and the user clicks up it will turn to 00:01:00:00

Comment: I will have to adjust it - and it's a very long code:(. I thought of a shorter solution